# Nice closed form for polynomial defined as an antiderivative

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $n$ be an integer $\geq 1$, and let $f_n(t)=(t(1-t))^n$. Let $F_n(t)$ denote the antiderivative of $f_n(t)$ satisfying $F_n(0)=0$. Of course, using Newton’s binomial formula we have an expansion for $F_n$ as a sum of $n+1$ monomials in $t$. But I ask if there is a formula for $F_n$ without such a sum with a non-constant number of terms. To be more precise, I’m asking  if there is a closed formula
containing only constants, $+$ (not $\Sigma_{k=0}^n$), $-,\times,$ division and exponentiation, and also the operator $\Pi_{k=0}^n$ (so that, e.g., something like

$$\Pi_{k=0}^n (t-7k)^{2+k} +\Pi_{k=0}^n (t+8k)^{k-1}$$

is OK. )

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure how  much this helps your cause, but I do recognize $F_n(t)$ as defined as being an [Incomplete Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).  Now, the standard definition is in terms of a series.  That said, I did find a representation as a [continued fraction](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17) as follows:

$$F_n(t) = \frac{[t (1-t)]^{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{1}{1 + } \frac{d_1}{1 + } \frac{d_2}{1 + } \frac{d_3}{1 + } \ldots$$

where

$$d_{2 k} = \frac{k (n+1-k) t}{n+2 k)(n+2 k+1)}$$

$$d_{2 k+1} =- \frac{(n+1+k) (2 n+2 +k)}{(n+2 k+1)(n+2 k +2)}$$

Perhaps this isn't exactly a closed form, but it isn't a series either.